# NodeJs api com promisses

Tags: node.js, api, design-pattern, promises

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em TypeScript com NodeJS e MariaDB; quando faço uma operação com o banco, logo abaixo possuo um **if** para verificar se ocorreu algum erro.

```
productDao.save({name:"Notebook Dell", price:"5000"}, function(err, res){
   if(err){
      //Código para caso algo dê errado.
   }else{
      //Código se tudo der certo.
   }
})
```

O caso é: Posso utilizar *promises* em uma API? Gostaria que ficasse algo assim:

```
productDao.save({name:"Notebook Dell", price:"5000"})
.then(res => {
   //Caso tudo dê certo.
})
.catch(err => {
   //Caso algo dê errado.
})
```

Porém, me pergunto, A padrão *promise* é ideal para uma API? Quais as possíveis complicações? Quais seriam as desvantagens e vantagens sobre esta arquitetura em uma **API**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar Promises ou Callbacks "à moda antiga" como preferires. A abordagem com promises tem vantagens:

- erros lançados dentro de uma promise chamam o `catch` e não param o script, ao contrário de uma função normal que pára a execução quando houver erros
- a promise permite encadeamento e ser incluída em funções de alta ordem como o `Promise.all`

Em relação a API, é uma questão de preferência.

Comment: Sem falar que usando Promises o código fica bem mais legível :)